# Intersection of fixed point subspaces

Tags: general-topology, finite-groups, group-actions, transversality

Let a finite group ***G*** act smoothly on a smooth manifold ***M*** of dimension ***n***. Let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be subgroups of ***G*** and assume that **dim**$(M^{H_1})+$**dim**$(M^{H_2})=n$. I have two questions:

1. How to show that $M^{H_1}$ and $M^{H_2}$ are smooth submanifolds of $M$?
2. Assume additionally that $M^G$ is of dimension $0$ and that $H_1\cup H_2$ generates $G$. Is it true that $M^{H_1}$ and $M^{H_2}$ are transverse?

---

Comment: 1: Yes. 2: No. What did you try to solve this?

Comment: I made the conditions in 2. more rigid - I think it may hold but cannot prove it. Yeah, before, there were obvious cases when it didn't hold, e.g. H_1=H_2.